# ZFC+``every analytical set is measurable"

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

I know that "ZFC+the existence of an inaccessible cardinal" is equconsistent to
"ZFC + every $\mathbf{\Sigma}^1_3$ set is measurable".

Then how about the light face case?

Without large cardinal assumption, can we have a ZFC model in which every analytical set (or  lightface $\Sigma^1_3$) is measurable?

Here a set is analytical if it is $\Sigma^1_n$ for some $n$.

Edited:

This was already answered by Shelah. 
''It is known that there is a generic extension of $L$ not collapsing cardinals nor violating CH, in which every definable (with no parameter!) set of reals is measurable..." from the 3rd remark, page 18, Shelah's paper.

Comment: I always thought that analytic sets are $\Sigma^1_1$, then you have co-analytic as $\Pi^1_1$ and the rest are just named "projective sets".

Comment: You are right. But analytical set is another thing. This follows from Moschovakis's book.

Comment: I think Solovay's argument actually shows that "every $\Sigma^1_3(a)$-set is measurable" is equivalent to $\aleph_1^{L[a]} \lt \aleph_1$.

Comment: I agree with you. We just need to collapse the first uncountable cardinal in $L$ to get a zfc model in which every analytical set is measurable.

Comment: To answer Asaf's comment/question, "analytic" means boldface $\mathbf{\Sigma^1_1}$ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set); and "analytical" (with an "-al" suffix) means lightface $\Sigma^1_n$ for some $n$ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_hierarchy).  Hence the analytical sets are the effective projective sets.  I was confused myself and had to look it up.

Comment: Jason, thanks! Now I know, and knowing is half the battle!

Comment: I see that this question already answered itself, but I thought I'd mention that a similar phenomenon also happens with determinacy in place of measurability, e.g., in the Kechris--Solovay paper "On the relative consistency strength of determinacy hypotheses" where it is shown that OD determinacy is much weaker than OD$_\mathbb{R}$-determinacy.